# How to get the href src value from a string

Tags: javascript, regex

[image]
 A string contains entire value of a html.i need to get the value of href tag i.e. src value.please help me to solve.

```
         var alltext="a href="images/BGL30NA-10.JPG" target="""
         var str=allText;
```

Comment: I smell a X, Y problem here. What are you trying to do? I looks like you're inserting and manipulate html with composed string values. I think there are better options to do that.

Comment: i want to get the href tag value(i.e. images/BGL30NA-10.JPG).I have the content in a string(i.e alltext)

Comment: Is the string hard coded? If not, how are you composing this string?

Comment: No,String contains a html file content,it is dynamically generated

Comment: Wouldn't it be more efficient to alter the value at the point where it is dynamically generated?

Comment: i got the exact solution,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
'a href="images/BGL30NA-10.JPG" target=""'.match(/href="(.*?)"/)[1]
```

try this regex .

Answer (score 1):

if you using jQuery:

try this:

```
var href = $('a').attr('href')
```

but better if you have `<a></a>` with something `id` and then

```
var href = $('#youId').attr('href')
```

Comment: Gladys ,i have the html content in a string only.so help to get the string by using regx or substring

Answer (score 1):

hope this may help you.

try this, it will gives the value of href in `javascript`, below work only if you assign `id` attribute in your anchor tag `<a href="images\images1.jpg" id="image1">`

**for only value of href**
`document.getElementById("image1").getAttribute("href");` here is [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yashsoni789/n1sxk3s5/)

if you want to get full path then use this:

**for full path of href** `document.getElementById("aaa").href;`   here is [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yashsoni789/n1sxk3s5/1/)

if you have any doubts, ask it in below comment. @sriram

Answer (score 1):

[**Parse the string before**](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/) and use appropriate DOM functions:

```
str = "hello, <b>my name is</b> jQuery.";
html = $.parseHTML( str );
# use $('a').attr('href') or any other selector here
```

The mandatory link to **[TONY THE PONY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)**.